# Taking a break between jobs

Tags: job-change, india

I have about 15 years of work experience in IT and in a management position. I feel it's a good time to take a break of 6 months, recharge myself, learn some new skills and get back to a new job more refreshed.

However, I am not sure how the market will react to a break in the career. Has anyone done something similar in the Indian market and how has it been perceived? Did you face difficulties in getting a new job?

Comment: I don't know about India, but I know several people in Europe who took a 6-12 months break while having significantly less work experience than you and didn't experience much trouble, because of rather high demand on the IT market.

Answer (score 6):

I can't speak for India in particular but of the people I've interviewed every once and a while you end up with people with a 1 - 6 month resume gap where they just took time to themselves.

Most of the time the reason given is something like "I was traveling the world", or "I went on a road trip all over the country" or "I sailed down the entire Atlantic coast" honestly the specific reason isn't that important. The person decided there was something they wanted/needed and they made it happen. Honestly to me personally that speaks highly of their character, they set a goal and saw it through.

The employment gap was no issue at all. Honestly I think it only starts to look bad when you start creeping up to 8+ months. Otherwise I don't think it'll have a negative impact on your resume.